# Using ng-bind-html with textAngular

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html, textangular

I have created a feature in my application wherein one can copy contents of an existing invoice to create a fresh new invoice. All other fields are getting copied. But the field 'note to customer' isn't getting displayed somehow. I've used text angular for adding a 'note to customer'.

```
    <div layout="row"  flex>
        <div flex-xl="" ng-if="documentEntity.noteToCustomer"
            ng-click="noteToCustomer($event,documentEntity.noteToCustomer)"
            style="border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12); background-color: #fdf7f7; padding: 15px; border-width: 2 0 1px; line-height: 26px; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; float: left;"
            class="flex-xl" ><span ng-bind-html="documentEntity.noteToCustomer"></span></div>

    </div>
```

What might be the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

text angular directive is missing in above

```
<div  text-angular flex-xl="" ng-if="documentEntity.noteToCustomer" ....>...</div>
```

add a plunker for clear understanding..

Answer (score 0):

In the documentarion of textangular, something is said about using `ng-bind-html`. Try using `ta-bing` instead.